# Automatically add all JS files to the index.html

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gruntjs

I am building an AngularJS application and I use Grunt. Is it usual to have some kind of configuraiton that includes all JS files in the index.html?

In the ngBoilerplate project (https://github.com/ngbp/ngbp/blob/v0.3.1-release/src/index.html)

```
<!-- compiled JavaScript --><% scripts.forEach( function ( file ) { %>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%= file %>"></script><% }); %>
```

But I have used the Yeoman AngularJS generator. The above line does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I think its more typical to create a grunt task to concatenate all your JS files into a single one.  You can see here for the library to do that: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-concat

That being said the code you provided should work but it looks like it will depend on PHP(?) to run the loop and print out the filename location for each script. You can check the output of the source file and make sure you can view the included JS file. It's possible the path is being printed out incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

I personally would prefer to use some module loader, e.g. [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/).

It will allow to handle separate scripts as **modules with dependencies**. 
A must-have thingy for medium and large projects anyway.